# Controller recebendo parametro array como null

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Estou fazendo uma requisição AJAX, mas não consigo passar array...

Minha controller está assim:

```
[Route("imoveis/BuscaDados/Json/Listas/ListaQuartos")]
    public JsonResult ListaQuartos(int idEstado, int idCidade, int[] idsBairros, int[] idStatus)
    {
        RealizaBuscaListas.BuscaNumQuartos(idEstado, idCidade, idsBairros.ToList(), IdsStatus);
        return Json(RealizaBuscaListas.ListaDeQuartos, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

E minha função javascript assim:

```
function preencheQuartos(Destino) {
var idEstado = 0;
var idCidade = 0;
var idsBairros = [];
idsBairros[0] = 1
idsBairros[1] = 2
var idStatus = [0];
Url = baseUrl + "imoveis/BuscaDados/Json/Listas/ListaQuartos/";
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: Url,
    data: { idEstado: idEstado, idCidade: idCidade, idsBairros: idsBairros, idStatus: idStatus },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, quarto) {
            Faz coisas...
        });
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Falha! Não foi possível retornar os números de quartos, tente novamente.");
    }
});
}
```

Porém ao inspecionar a action, percebo que os parametros int[] idsBairros e int[] idStatus sempre chegam nulos.
Será que terei que montar a url inteira com um looping para cada item dos arrays?

Comment: Já tentou mudar o tipo do parâmetro somente pra testes? Tenta mudar pra object e vê se envia certo. Ou tenta soltar um stringfy no array antes de enviar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver adicionando à reuisição o **traditional:true**,

```
$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: Url,
    traditional:true,
    data: { idEstado: idEstado, idCidade: idCidade, idsBairros: idsBairros, idStatus: idStatus },
```